# Open :make output window to the right

Tags: vim, neovim

Currently, while running the `make` command (`BufWritePost`) the window opens from the bottom pane, How can I change it to appear from the left side, or use a separate split window for showing the make output (realtime).

`:vert make` is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it but you can use a different command:

```
:vert term make
```

The above is for Vim, I think you need to create a new window first in Neovim.

Comment: Thanks, I combined it with `watch` to show realtime output.